# How to Compile F# with Mono 3.2.3?

Tags: f#, mono

I can't compile F# using Mono 3.2.3

I'm facing this error with sgen and couldn't work around it

```
ayhid@localhost ~/m/fsharp> make                                                                          master!
make -C src/fsharp all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ayhid/work/fsharp/src/fsharp'
make do-proto
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ayhid/work/fsharp/src/fsharp'
make -C FSharp.Build-proto do-proto
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ayhid/work/fsharp/src/fsharp/FSharp.Build-proto'
mono  /home/ayhid/work/fsharp/lib/bootstrap/4.0/../2.0/fssrgen.exe ../FSharp.Build/FSBuild.txt .libs/proto/FSBuild.fs .libs/proto/FSBuild.resx

Native stacktrace:

    mono() [0x4b4761]
    mono() [0x4235bf]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x35f3e0efa0]
    mono() [0x5de1e8]
    mono() [0x5de77c]
    mono() [0x5d38cf]
    mono() [0x5d3ac4]
    mono() [0x5d554c]
    mono() [0x5d6194]
    mono() [0x5d9b58]
    mono() [0x5eeee8]
    mono() [0x5ef6f2]
    mono() [0x586e0b]
    mono(mono_runtime_init+0x109) [0x59fae9]
    mono() [0x424155]
    mono(mono_main+0x2e8) [0x489cc8]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x35f3621b75]
    mono() [0x419d05]

Debug info from gdb:

Mono support loaded.
Mono support loaded.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00000035f3e0eb0c in waitpid () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    Thread 0x7f6d391e07c0 (LWP 2608) "mono" 0x00000035f3e0eb0c in waitpid () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f6d391e07c0 (LWP 2608)):
#0  0x00000035f3e0eb0c in waitpid () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000004b4868 in mono_handle_native_sigsegv ()
#2  0x00000000004235bf in mono_sigsegv_signal_handler ()
#3  <signal handler called>
#4  0x00000000005de1e8 in major_copy_or_mark_object ()
#5  0x00000000005de77c in major_scan_object ()
#6  0x00000000005d38cf in sgen_drain_gray_stack ()
#7  0x00000000005d3ac4 in job_scan_from_registered_roots ()
#8  0x00000000005d554c in major_copy_or_mark_from_roots ()
#9  0x00000000005d6194 in major_do_collection ()
#10 0x00000000005d9b58 in sgen_perform_collection ()
#11 0x00000000005eeee8 in alloc_degraded ()
#12 0x00000000005ef6f2 in mono_gc_alloc_mature ()
#13 0x0000000000586e0b in mono_thread_attach_full ()
#14 0x000000000059fae9 in mono_runtime_init ()
#15 0x0000000000424155 in mini_init ()
#16 0x0000000000489cc8 in mono_main ()
#17 0x00000035f3621b75 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#18 0x0000000000419d05 in _start ()

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

make[3]: *** [.libs/proto/FSBuild.resources] Aborted (core dumped)
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ayhid/work/fsharp/src/fsharp/FSharp.Build-proto'
make[2]: *** [do-proto] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ayhid/work/fsharp/src/fsharp'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ayhid/work/fsharp/src/fsharp'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to comment out the sgen part in configure.ac, and nothing changed.

I had no problem compiling it with Mono 2.10.

Comment: Did you run ./autogen.sh

Comment: @JohnPalmer Yes, I did. ./autogen.sh --prefix /usr

Comment: try mono master, there has been a fix which was not included in mono 3.2.3, which I think you're hitting